# Creating gant charts in Google Sheets using conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a dynamic gant chart in google sheets.  Is there a way for me to colour code a date range on a row section based on a start and end date outlined on the same row.

Thank you for any help.

John

Answer (score 2):

I've set up an example sheet that might work for you

https://goo.gl/KjuxBF

You can add up to 100 tasks in column A with dates in B & C and the conditional formatting should draw the bar for you

Comment: Unsure why this isn't the accepted solution or has more upvotes! Was able to repurpose this into my own solution. 100 Thanks my friend.

Comment: p.s did you use an app script to reset the sheet?